# Open Microsoft Outlook from a Web application to display .msg files

Tags: web-applications, outlook, msg

I have emails stored on an http server in Microsoft Outlook format (.msg files). My web app shows links to these files. Simply clicking a link downloads the file to my local machine.

Is there a way to open Microsoft Outlook when I click such a link and display the email in Outlook? Even better if I could avoid the download completely and have Outlook work directly with the link. I have already associated .msg files with Outlook in the control panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can automate Outlook from a JavaScript. Note, it will be working only in Internet Explorer. See [Compose and Send E-mail from JavaScript by using Outlook Automation 2007](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rajnishkaushik/2007/05/06/compose-and-send-e-mail-from-javascript-by-using-outlook-automation-2007/) for more information.

In a common scenario the best you can do is to save the .msg file on the disk and associate the extension with Outlook.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, @EugeneAstafiev.